# Change values of rows by a list data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I'm having hard times trying to update data from a dataframe on specifics indexes.

Example DataFrame:

```
    author   episode_number      episode_title  quote     
0   Monica              1.0           Roommate     Hi  
1   Monica              1.0           Roommate     Ho
2   Monica              1.0           Roommate     Ha
3   Monica              1.0           Roommate     He
4   Monica              1.0           Roommate     Hu
...    ...              ...                ...    ...
61125 rows × 4 columns
```

What I'm trying to do is: having an range of indexes, I want to update the data from an specific column of the dataset by a list of values.

E.g.: Change all the values from the "author" column from index 100 to 200 by the values present in a list with the same size (100).

I've been thinking of using something like iterrows() but I know that's a anti-pattern solution. So what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is one way

```py
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df.iloc[1:4, 0] = names  # +1 to the length (e.g. 100:201)

print(df)

   author  episode_number episode_title quote
0  Monica             1.0      Roommate    Hi
1       a             1.0      Roommate    Ho
2       b             1.0      Roommate    Ha
3       c             1.0      Roommate    He
4  Monica             1.0      Roommate    Hu
```